# Why is there an error in the solution set of the piecewise function of the logarithmic function?

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

```
In[41]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Log[2, x], x > 0}, {Log[1/2, -x], x < 0}}]

In[43]:= Reduce[{f[a] == f[-a]}, a]

Out[43]= a == -1 || a == 0 || a == 1
```

The solution set has a==0, and the true number of logarithms cannot be equal to 0

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{Log[2, x], x > 0}, {Log[1/2, -x], x < 0}}];

Reduce[{f[a] == f[-a]}, a, Reals]` returns the input and "Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce".

Comment: `Piecevise` automatically sets default value zero: `Piecewise[{{Subscript[val, 1],Subscript[cond, 1]},\[Ellipsis]},val]
uses default value val if none of the Subscript[cond, i] apply. The default for val is 0. ` That's why `f[0]=0`. Try `Which[x > 0, Log[2, x], x < 0, Log[1/2, -x]]` alternatively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Log[2, x], x > 0}, {Log[1/2, -x], x < 0}}]
```

[image]

```
f[0]

(* 0 *)
```

You have defined `f[0] == 0`, `Log` is not involved. If you want `f[0]` to have a different value you must specify it.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Log[2, x], x > 0}, {Log[1/2, -x], x < 0}, {Undefined, 
     x == 0}}] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
f[0]

(* Undefined *)

Reduce[{f[a] == f[-a]}, a]

(* a == -1 || a == 1 *)
```